# Kubuntu - Title bars too small

Tags: kubuntu, kde, kde5

[image]

How do I fix these title bars? It happens with a lot of the custom themes, such as Materia Manjaro Dark. It's a fresh 19.10 Kubuntu install.

Comment: And you have no problem with the default themes?

Comment: No problem. The default themes work fine. Lots of custom themes work just fine as well, while another lot suffers from the described issue.

Comment: And are you on the default plasma version or have you installed https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/backports?field.series_filter=eoan to give you an more recent plasma version? I've updated my Kubuntu 19.10 with Plasma 5.17.90 and I'll take a look. Are these themes from the KDE Store?

Comment: I'm on Operating System: Kubuntu 19.10 • KDE Plasma Version: 5.17.90 • KDE Frameworks Version: 5.66.0 • Qt Version: 5.12.4 • Kernel Version: 5.3.0-29-generic • OS Type: 64-bit. I just installed Manjaro Materia Dark via `System Settings > Application Style > Window Decorations > Get New Window Decorations`. All three options seem to be fine for me with Dolphin, Kate, and Konsole.

Comment: @DKBose Operating System: Kubuntu 19.10 • KDE Plasma Version: 5.16.5 • KDE Frameworks Version: 5.62.0 • Qt Version: 5.12.4 • Kernel Version: 5.3.0-29-genericOS || It's a fresh 19.10 Kubuntu install with the minimal option selected. I have followed the same procedure as you did, lots of themes behave incorrectly, as seen here (https://i.imgur.com/6auoy1Y.png). The previous time I tried to install Kubuntu, I had the same exact problem.

Comment: I guess you have options: stick with the default window decorations or try the ppa. The ppa is made by the Kubuntu team and is pretty stable. Of course, there's a chance that even that ppa may not fix the issue. I'm actually testing the [beta ppa](https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/beta) which gives me a preview of what 20.04 will look like. My main machine has Kubuntu 18.04. I'll try those themes and report back.

Comment: The Manjaro Materia Dark is working fine there as well so I don't know why things aren't working for you. Sorry, but I don't know what to suggest!

Comment: Since lots of other things seem not to work here as well, I will install Ubuntu instead and perhaps try the ppa there as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try going to `System Settings > Fonts` and then select the `Force font DPI` option. 96 DPI did the trick for me.

This will, however, increase the size of other GUI elements too, and not just the title bars.

---

Here's a screenshot of the option:

[image: Option screenshot]